# Overidding list values

Tags: java, arraylist, resultset

retrieveemails method job is to retrieve confirmations from DB

following is the DB details

```
memberId keyId key perftype emailaddress confirmed acceptconfirmation created_date confirmed_date
121212  94947585  010  temp    xx.@gmail.com yes       No                29/06/2011  29/06/2011  
121212  545454585  010  perm    yy.@gmail.com yes       No                29/06/2011  29/06/2011
```

Problem is i am retrieving the values from resultset and setting the values to Confirmation(pojo/ setters and getters ) , up to now first row is setting and added in list(Actiontype),but for second row the values are replacing in list.

How can i add these two different rows in Action??

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `Confirmation` for each iteration in your loop, otherwise you are just overwriting the values in each iteration and adding the same object again.

Try like this:

```
while(resultSet.next()){
    Confirmation confirm = new Confirmation(); //moved this line from top of class to here
    confirm.setConfirmed(Boolean.parseBoolean(resultSet.getString("confirmed")));
    confirm.setConfType(resultSet.getString("conftype"));
    confirm.setContactID(resultSet.getString("contactId"));
    confirm.setEmailAddress(resultSet.getString("Emailaddress"));
    confirm.setPartyID(resultSet.getString("partyID"));
    confirmations.add(confirm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create new instance of object `Confirmation` after start of while loop:

```
while(resultSet.next()){
confirm = new Confirmation();
```

Comment: i am thinking that i need to override equals() and hashCode() methods :) but your suggestion is good thank you,

Comment: thanks to stackoverflow, thanku Alexander Podkuntin ,working now